# Need help inserting json literal into mysql 5.7

Tags: mysql, json

When I try to insert the following query I keep getting this error message:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '['php','javascript'])' at line 2

I am using the following query

```
INSERT INTO freelancer (tags) VALUES (['php','javascript']);
```

I tried another query, this time making it a string, and then I get this error

```
INSERT INTO freelancer (tags) VALUES ("['php','javascript']");
```

Invalid JSON text: "Invalid value." at position 1 in value for column 'freelancer.tags'.

I am not sure how to go about inserting this into mysql... if anyone can help me figure this out, I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON is very particular about quotes. You *must* use doubles:

```
VALUES ('["php","javascript"]')
```

You can test with a [JSON validator](https://jsonlint.com) if you're curious about what is or isn't JSON.